# Firefox - When I close a tab, I would like the one to the left to be activated

Tags: firefox, tabs

I have googled quite a bit for the answer to this but it's hard to find the correct keywords.

When I close a tab in Firefox, eg using `CTRL`+`W`, it activates the tab to the right (unless the tab I'm closing is the rightmost one).

I find this annoying as usually I've opened links in new tabs, which open to the right, so when I close the current tab I want to go back to the original tab that I came from.

Eg, I have three tabs open and the middle one is active:

[image: three tabs open]

Then I close the middle tab and the one to the right of it gets activated:

[image: two tabs open]

I want testing1 to be activated instead.

Is there a way to achieve this **without** installing an extension?

Tab mix plus used to do this but I would rather not install an extension just for this specific behavior.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there isn't a built-in option in Firefox to change the tab activation behavior when closing a tab. Firefox's default behavior is to activate the tab to the right when you close a tab, and there are no `about:config` settings to change this behavior.

To achieve this behavior, you will most likely need an extension. I understand that you prefer not to use an extension, but I think, it is the only way to modify this specific behavior in Firefox.

This is an extension that you can use to achieve this behavior: [Select After Closing Current](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/select-after-closing-current/)

It allows you to customize the behavior of Firefox when closing a tab. After installing the extension, configure it to activate the previously active tab when closing the current one.

Although this isn't the ideal solution you were looking for, it will help you achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: I'm just not a fan of installing an extension that has the ability to "obtain the URL, title, and icon from any tab" - basically access to the entire browsing history, just to fix this specific, fairly minor problem. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/permission-request-messages-firefox-extensions#w_access-browser-tabs The thing is, I'm 99% sure that Firefox used to not do this - may have been Tab Mix Plus... but I do feel the tab close behavior has changed more recently than when TMP was killed. I don't think this happens on my other PC at home, will have to check.

Comment: Actually my PC at home does have the same unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 1):

What is your? `browser.selectOwnerOnClose` set to?
If that's set to false it will open tab to the right if available, otherwise will open to the left.
I had the opposite issue of you so maybe this will work.

Docs: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.tabs.selectOwnerOnClose

The caveats are particularly odd and really valuable to note.

browser.link.open_newwindow must be set to 3 for this preference to have an effect.
This preference does not apply to tabs opened by middle-clicking or [Ctrl]-clicking links.

Comment: `browser.link.open_newwindow` is set to 3, `browser.tabs.selectOwnerOnClose` is set to true.